# CSS Shadows (how to get rid of top shadow?)

Tags: css, shadows

Got a problem with the css shadows.
I can't figure out how to get rid of the top shadow here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1p1r.png

What I got:

```
box-shadow: 0 -3px 4px -6px #777, 0 3px 4px 6px #ccc;
```

How do I do that? I want it to be on the left, right and bottom side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like so:

```
  box-shadow:   3px 3px 3px #777, -3px 3px 3px #777;
```

(adjust hex colours to match your needs)

Example - http://jsbin.com/ebemol/1

Answer (score 2):

```
try this is:

 div
    {
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:white;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #888888;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to position the vertical shadow property:

```
box-shadow: 0 5px 4px -6px #777
```

`-3px` would indicates that the shadow starts -3px from where the shadow would start normally, I have changed it to an arbitrary value, `5px` so it starts further down.

http://jsfiddle.net/9Dgtj/

You can see from the JS Fiddle I have provided that adjusting the vertical shadow (5px) moves the shadow down.

Comment: @Ingo - but it changed.  Increase the value accordingly!

Comment: Oh wait. I don't need the second part after "," ? I see.